# какой из циклов лучше использовать fasm?

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

есть примеры циклов:

```
mov cx, 10 ; кол-во повторений
loop: ; метка
    dec cx ; декремент cx
    ; любые действия где cx итерация (обратная)
    jcxz end ;если cx == 0 то перепрыгнуть
    jmp loop ;Иначе продолжить цикл
end:
    ;конец цикла
```

и

```
.while al=1
 ; код
.endw
```

есть ли между ними какая-то разница? какой стоит использовать в fasm'е?

Comment: Разница уже хотя бы в условиях цикла. А вообще, моё мнение состоит в том, что лучше не использовать высокоуровневые директивы в ассемблере. На то он и ассемблер, чтобы вы полностью контролировали и должным образом оптимизировали код, который пишете. В первом вашем примере вы  контролируете код, самостоятельно определяете его инструкции, структуру. А во втором - полагаетесь на милость транслятора сделать это за вас, тем самым код может получиться не слишком оптимальным, и даже содержать неявные ошибки.

Comment: понял, спасибо!